# How to include/exclude specific class from Maven Shader

Tags: java, maven

I'm having an issue with the maven shader plug-in I have configured for my Java project. It is removing a certain class within a dependency that I need, which causes a ClassNotFoundException at runtime.

The class in question is SnappyCodec.class, which you can see is present when viewing the dependency in Intellij's package explorer: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW5Zs.png).

So the class is present and referenced, but when I package it using maven and subseuently unpackage the jar to inspect it, I find that the codec folder is still present with *some* classes in it, but SnappyCodec.class has been removed.

Here is the dependency artifact in question:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
         <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
         <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried multiple ways of trying to exclude it from being touched by the shade plugin, but here is my current filter for the shade plugin:

```
    <filter>
         <artifact>org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro</artifact>
         <excludes>
              <exclude>**</exclude>
         </excludes>
    </filter>
```

which is within the `<configuration>` tag of my pom.

How can I make sure this specific class is not touched by the maven shade plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. For some reason finding this in the maven documentation was a challenge for me, but the answer lied there.

I needed to add the following filters to the configuration of my maven shade plugin:

```
<filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop</artifact>
    <includes>
          <include>**</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
<filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.parquet:parquet-column</artifact>
    <includes>
          <include>**</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
<filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding</artifact>
    <includes>
          <include>**</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
```

Basically, maven-shade was shading seemingly random classes from the parquet-hadoop artifact, so by adding the `<include>` filter, maven-shade did NOT shade any of the classes inside it.

After doing this, I needed to add the other two filters because by using the `<include>` tag on the parquet-hadoop artifact, it then excluded every other parquet-* artifact from being added to the compiled jar. So, I needed to explicitly tell it to include parquet-column and parquet-encoding as well since my application used those artifacts.

This configuration meant that maven-shader would not touch these three artifacts, meaning that any and every class that was present within those artifacts before compile time would remain there after compiling/packaging them with maven (thus, would be there at runtime, wheras they weren't before, causing the original error). Awesome!